# Java POI last CellStyle overwriting previous CellStyles

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm building an Excel file using the Apache POI library in Java. I want to have multiple cells with different colors, so I created a method for building the styles I need. Then, I am calling this method to apply the styles as I need them.

Unfortunately, the last foreground color is getting applied to all previous cells to which a style with a foreground color was applied. So, the yellow cell that I create in column A comes out grey when I create the grey cell in column C. [edited]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the method (sorry for its inelegance) [edited]:

```
private CellStyle getCellStyle(boolean isHeader, boolean isShaded, String color){
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    Font font = workbook.createFont();

    if (isHeader) {
        style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
    }

    if (isShaded) {
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow"))
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
        else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("light grey"));
            style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
    }

    style.setFont(font);

    return style;

}
```

And here is a section in which I call the method [edited].

```
private void createHeaderRow(Row row, String year, String tableName) {
    int rowNum = row.getRowNum();
    int colNum = 0;
    boolean isHeader = true;

    CellStyle boldStyle = getCellStyle(isHeader, false, "");
    CellStyle yellowStyle = getCellStyle(isHeader, true, "yellow");
    CellStyle lightGreyStyle = getCellStyle(isHeader, true, "light grey");

    Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
    cell.setCellValue(year);
    cell.setCellStyle(yellowStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("Company");
    cell.setCellStyle(boldStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("Total");
    cell.setCellStyle(lightGreyStyle);
}
```

Comment: for a test, try to simplify your code so that is simply just creates 3 or 4 cells with each value, as I wondering whether there is some coding error with the loops or `mergedRegions` etc.

Comment: Please also state which version of POI you are using and try with the latest one to rule out that this was fixed already.

Comment: Hi, both, thanks. I've removed the loops and merges. I'm not sure which version of POI I'm using...how can I determine that?

Comment: @Jamie the version should be mentionned in the name of the .jar, something like `poi-X.XX-dddd.jar` where X is the version number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not in Poi, see here :

```
 else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("light grey")); // <--- HERE
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
```

Your `else if` is not doing anything, and `style.setFillForegroundColor(..GREY..)` is called every time.

Using braces for condition is good practice even if not necessary.

FIFY :

```
if (isShaded) {
    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow")){
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
    }
    else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("light grey")){
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
    }
}
```

Just tested this code, seems to work fine for me

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that.